# Find style references that don't exist

Tags: css

Is there a tool that will find for me all the css classes that I am referencing in my HTML that don't actually exist?

ie. if I have <ul class="topnav" /> in my HTML and the topnav class doesn't exist in any of the referenced CSS files.

This is similar to [SO#33242](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website), which asks how to find unused CSS styles. This isn't a duplicate, as that question asks which CSS classes are not used.  This is the opposite problem.

Comment: This is a duplicate of SO#33242
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website

Comment: Reopened. Sorry - I hadn't realized that you were asking the reverse of that other question.

Comment: They're both valid questions, but they could possibly be merged if they were worded a bit differently, since they are both aspects of the same issue. Just a thought :)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate thread to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions

Comment: @DavidHobs No it isn't. This is the opposite question to the one you referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this JavaScript in the page that can perform this task for you:

```
function forItems(a, f) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) f(a.item(i))
}

function classExists(className) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('\\.' + className + '\\b'), found = false

  try {
    forItems(document.styleSheets, function(ss) {
      // decompose only screen stylesheets
      if (!ss.media.length || /\b(all|screen)\b/.test(ss.media.mediaText))
        forItems(ss.cssRules, function(r) {
          // ignore rules other than style rules
          if (r.type == CSSRule.STYLE_RULE && r.selectorText.match(pattern)) {
            found = true
            throw "found"
          }
        })
    })
  } catch(e) {}


  return found
}
```

Comment: great code snippet! I just grabbed this to help me find CSS classes referenced that don't exist.  Of course the trouble is that sometimes the class attribute is "overloaded" to provide a JavaScript hook ;-) but now I can at least see which ones have no styling applied. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Error Console in Firefox. Although, it gives **all** CSS errors, so you have to read through it.

Answer (score 0):

[IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/html_css_editor.html) tool does that as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This Firefox extension](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) is does exactly what you want.

It locates all unused selectors.

Comment: This is not the problem I'm trying to solve, I want to find all class attributes in the HTML that don't correspond to class names in the CSS.

Comment: Agree with @Deeksy - I too grabbed dustmeselectors once... but it would flag stuff that was defined, but used elsewhere on my site.  Thus you need to aggregate a bunch of data from multiple pages to ensure you truly have a "dead" selector. @mislav's answer is bang on.