# How can I remove unused CSS classes from my website project?

Tags: asp.net, css

My project has collected CSS entropy (unused classes) during its course of development.

Now in order to keep the CSS file small, I want to remove all unused CSS references. But doing that manually involves searching for each class in the entire project. That takes time.

Do you know of any way/tool which I can adopt to find out which CSS classes are no longer used in my project, and remove it?

I am programming on ASP.NET. Visual Studio.

Comment: See almost-identical question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might find this Firefox extension useful: http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/

Comment: It looks like there is a new version v3.0 available on the author's website, as well as a version for Opera - http://www.brothercake.com/

Comment: There is a new 4 version from the mozilla site: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

Answer (score 13):

In the Chrome Browser, press F12, go to the Audit tab, choose the "Reload page and audit on Load" option, and refresh the page. Chrome will list all the unused CSS rules.

For an online solution, go to [unused-css.com](https://unused-css.com/).

Comment: he wants a solution, not an audit, chrome browser only shows unused classes, but doesn't clean them

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a tool which allows you to find all class and CssClass attributes in your aspx source code.

See my [blog entry](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/04/21/checking-aspnet-source-code-with-graspx-part-2/) for info and download.