# Remove unused css classes

Tags: css

I'm making template. In css file are many css classes, which are no longer used in the template. It takes a long time to find and remove them manually.

Is there any tool that will find and remove unused css classes?

Comment: Have you tried google? I justed googled it and had bunch of great results on the first page. It has been asked here in the past as well...

Comment: @vsync thnks.. Not, i'm not tried. Now try

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7407220/104380 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/1761242/104380 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/12091356/104380 and a million more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Firefox extension [Dust-Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/.)

**OR**

you may also try [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)

This Chrome developer tool has an **Audits** tab which can shows unused CSS selectors.

Run an audit **>** under **Web Page Performance** see **Remove unused CSS rules**

**OR**

http://unused-css.com/ tool explores your all pages and removes unused CSS.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox "CSS Usage" Ad-dons is available.
[CSS Usage Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/)

Answer (score 2):

We Use Chrome's Audit feature. Very simple and easy to use. Below is the screenshot showing unsused CSS for gmail. By viewing this, you can remove the unnecessary ones.

This works even for localhost sites. (You need not move to public URL to test.)

[image: gmail's audit for Unused CSS]