# Is it possible to find all unused CSS?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to identify unused css definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions)

I have quite big CSS file, that already contains style definition for classes/elements that are not used by markup any more.

It is possible to find those quick?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Firefox extension Dust-Me at http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the Dust-Me Selectors plug in for Firefox to test pages individually or spider a whole site.