# stripping all the unnecessary attributes in an html document

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to identify unused css definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions)

I like to write a class for everything, I'm a class-freaker cause after writing an html document, it's more easy to manage the style of it and that way you can focus on the structure while coding more than how you will manage the styles of every containers and the typography of them.

Ok this is useful but you're not really saving bits, and especially if your document gets in length.

My website, at least the design, is done and I do not really think I'll be altering it (or if so I could add new classes for the pointed elements).

I'd like to know if there can be found some programs to which we give the stylesheets and the html documents so It can strips/monitors all the unused class/id attributes of.

Comment: I've not heard of anything that does what you suggest. I assume that you don't use the ids or classes in any javascript? And although you are right that styling is best done with classes why not just add classes when you need them to avoid this problem in future?

Comment: thanks pals and sorry for the duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a built in app like Firebug, open Chrome press Ctrl+Shift+J to bring it up, it will tell how many and which selectors you are using.

Comment: yes I know, but I don't feel like clicking on all elements to actually know what are the unused elements. Thanks for your comment though