# Is there a way to customize Google Chrome's Developer Console?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I consistently run into the need to clean up css files and strip unused css elements. I am aware that google chrome has the capability to display all the unused css elements on a page but there are times (like a project I am working on right now) where the original designer left hundreds of unused elements within this file.

So, my question here is -- does anyone know of a way to customize the google chrome developer console to export a list of all used CSS elements. Or, is anyone aware of an existing google chrome plugin which provides this functionality?

I realize there is a firefox plugin which provides these capabilities but I would love to find a similar solution for google chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Your title does not really match your question.

Comment: The usual thing people want is to show all *unused* CSS rules, which has been asked many, many times. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions. And your *title* ("Is there a way to customize Google Chrome's Developer Console?") does not match your *question* ("How do I show all used CSS rules?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways customizing the Google Chrome Web Inspector:

1. Web Inspector Options
   [image]
2. Chrome Extensions

   - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.devtools.console.html
   - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.devtools.audits.html

You could create an extension that does what you need.