# Is it possible to customize Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, edit

Is possible to edit the bootstrap.css file for license accordions?

I mean, I need to edit the general style, and I don't want to use one more css file.

Can I edit the original by hand?

Comment: You may also be interested in [Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if you're free to modify Bootstrap and use it. The answer is: yes of course!

PS. Bootstrap is licensed under the [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can. Open the file with a text editor and press some keys... `TA-DAAH!` File edited.

If your question actually is if that's a good practice in order to customize the framework, my answer is no. There's a [customization tool](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) to manage with the basic layout. For any further customization, write your own stylesheet and overwrite Bootstrap rules.
Why? Because in the future you will need a native component as it was, or you will want to update to the last version of the framework.

If your question is about licenses, as @spinningarrow answered, yes. You are free to edit at will.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **best practice** for modifying bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#customizing

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately @spinningarrow's comment is incorrect. Bootstrap is actually licensed under the Apache License Version 2 (APLv2). The license can be seen here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: Actually, it is MIT, look at this: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#license-faqs