# How to use bootstrap and LESS and keep a clean project?

Tags: css, version-control, twitter-bootstrap, project, less

I'm developing a web app using python and twitter-bootstrap, and my CSS would really benefit from using LESS in order to generate my styles and themes.  I want to inherit from classes provided by bootstrap, which means I've got to get the bootstrap source, and compile my LESS stylesheets against the boostrap .less files.

**My question is two-fold:**

1) The simplest way it seems to use LESS is not to actually compile stylesheets "on-the-fly" but to have a build step that I run each time I make changes to the styles.  Is this typical?  It seems like a lot of people run LESS dynamically in their server process, but it's an extra headache that I probably don't need, and I don't want to run less on the client side.

2) Thanks to LESS, my project now depends not just on bootstrap, but the bootstrap *"source"* - What's the best way to handle this in terms of my project management?  I don't want to just absorb the whole of whatever the current version of bootstrap is into my git repos, because it seems like it would be a hassle to update it as newer versions of bootstrap come out (also feels icky!)  Still though, I need to have at least the minified js/css in my project tree in order to deploy my app.  How do people typically handle dependencies like this when developing web apps?

Comment: You might be looking for [Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices).

Comment: I'm not actually interested in customizing bootstrap... at this point, I simply want to include some of its styles as mixins.  Still, it's a helpful link.

Comment: Are you using git, what about a sub module?

Answer (score 1):

1. There are a couple of shoices:

   1. You could [use less.js](http://lesscss.org/#usage) in development, so you don't have to
      compile each time you change your less code. You just use `*.less` files instead of `*.css`
   2. You could use any of the GUI tools that will automatically recompile less code. I prefer [LESS.app](http://incident57.com/less/).
2. I use `git submodule`

Answer (score 0):

I would have linked you to the same post as Pavlo above. Maybe there is no best CLEAN practice for this? Neither there is any magic "package manager" i think.

I went updates BS once and it was a bit of a hassle to find out all the variable names that have been changed in the LESS files.