# Customizing Roots Framework

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, less

My question is related to [Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices)

I'm using roots framework for a wordpress website.What are the best practices to modify roots/twitter bootstrap.For example,I want to change text colors like anchor,h1,h2 etc..,

Do I need to edit `variables.less` and recompile everything.

or

Add another `custom.less` file with the variables and import into `bootstrap.less`

Answer (score 0):

This is better asked on the [LESS Github page](https://github.com/cloudhead/less), but for better forward compatibility, I'd suggest creating a new `.less` file and add that path onto the end of `bootstrap.less`. Then, use a tool like [Codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) to compile.