# Twitter Bootstrap LESS css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am wondering why I cant set variables within twitter bootstrap using LESS. I am using ruby on rails which has a bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file. it has the following statement

```
    // Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
    //
    // Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
    // you may use and inherit here
    //
    // If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
    // See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html for their names and    documentation
    //
   // Example:
   // @linkColor: #ff0000;
```

So my understanding is that i can set my variables within here. So i set

```
  @black: #333;
```

and then tried using it in my application.css calling `@black` file but it does not work? i.e. doesn’t render `#333`.

Am i understanding this incorrectly?, do all my variables and css styling go within the bootstrap and override file?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions at http://lesscss.org/#usage to make sure your updated less is used, if you are using it client side.

OR

Compile your updated less into CSS and then copy over the updated CSS.
Here's a list of tools that can do the compile. http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html#compiling

For suggestions on how to organize your bootstrap modifications see the SO question     [Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices)

As an aside, I wouldn't recommend changing `@black`. Changing it would alter many, many things, including some you might not expect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are modifying your `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` file, but the one being used is the `application.css` file. 
If that was the case, of course it's is just natural not to reflect the changes you've made. You must compile your `.less` file first to `.css`. to reflect that changes to your `.css` file.

For a try, use LESS via the client-side and setup your environment like so:

For instance, in your `index.html` file, put

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="application.less" />
```

in the document head. and below it add

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Download the `less.js` file from [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.4.2.min.js). and put it inside your root directory, or you may of course customize the location and make the necessary path in the `href` attrib.

After doing the above, you're ready to modify your `application.less` file (not the application.css). You may copy you're existing custom styles from the `application.css` file.

`application.less` is where you should put your variables.

You may rename your `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` file into `application.less` and make sure it is the one linked to in the header tag.

For more info about LESS CSS checkout the [wiki](https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki).