# Modifying Bootstrap Starter template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to add a search bar in the middle and 2 placeholder's on the right-hand side of Bootstrap Starter Template.  I'd also like to change the color of the navbar.

What's the best way to do this?

Here is the link to the Template I am refering to.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you:

for example if u want to change the color of the navbar (for webkit-borwser):
after link to bootstrap styles in head of HTML file add this code:

```
<style>
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0, 163, 255), rgb(31, 92, 158));
}
</style>
```

you can find css class of bootstrap and live edit with InspectElemets tools on Chrome and FireBug AddOnes on FireFox borwser.

then add your change to the `<style></style>` after the main css bootstrap files...

Answer (score 0):

Read the [document](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) to study Bootstrap scaffolding

For changing the navbar color, if you are not serious in modifying the source files:

1. Inspect element(Chrome)
2. In the styles panel, you will see exactly where it is.[image]
3. Go edit the source file.

But according to this post [Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices), they said you should avoid making changes to the source files if possible. So, instead of editing the source file, you can create a new css file containing the modifications and then include it after bootstrap.css