# Twitter bootstrap with width > 1170px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

This might be a stupid question, but after looking around the world wide webs for a while, I could not find an answer.

I'm using twitter bootstrap's fluid grid system for my new site. I mocked up the homepage's container area to be wider than twitter's default 1170px (1506px).

The 1506px layout breaks down to:
12 columns each 98px (1176px) with 11 margins of 30px (330px)

1176+300 = 1506.

**So is there any way that I can just plug this width (1506) into twitter bootstrap without having to overhaul a bunch of LESS and CSS?**

Answer (score 5):

Looks like everything you need starts at line 111:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  ...

  .container,
  .navbar-static-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
  .span12 {
    width: 1170px;
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Explanation = '*show me the error of my ways*', '*share a wiser approach*, *admit to wanting your answer to have a better vote count (-1 loses to 0 all day)*'.

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT use the customizer at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ unless you drop and replace the 1200px grid.

Compile your own css will be the easiest way:
see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12029786/1596547 and also [Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices)

The example below set the min-width of this grid to 1536pixels (1536 x 864) grid width + gutter

1. fork twitter-bootstrap from github and clone locally
2. add your new 1536 variables to **less/variables.less** (before the 1200 variables, see below)
3. copy less/responsive-1200px-min.less to **less/responsive-1536px-min.less** "search and replace" 1200 with 1536:
4. import responsive-1536px-min.less `@import "responsive-1536px-min.less";` in **less/resposnive.less** (before the 1200 include)
5. Install the LESS command line tool via Node and run the following command:`$ lessc ./less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap.css`

variables for step 2.:

```
// 1536px min
@gridColumnWidth1536:     98px;
@gridGutterWidth1536:     30px;
@gridRowWidth1536:        (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth1536) + (@gridGutterWidth1536 * (@gridColumns - 1));

// 1536px min
@fluidGridColumnWidth1536:     percentage(@gridColumnWidth1536/@gridRowWidth1536);
@fluidGridGutterWidth1536:     percentage(@gridGutterWidth1536/@gridRowWidth1536);
```

Or not preferred create your own 1536 (1506) grid css and add it after the bootstrap css in your source.

**1536.css:**

```
   /* based on Bootstrap v2.3.2 */
@media (min-width: 1536px) {
  .row {
    margin-left: -30px;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  .row:before,
  .row:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
  }
  .row:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  [class*="span"] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .container,
  .navbar-static-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 1506px;
  }
  .span12 {
    width: 1506px;
  }
  .span11 {
    width: 1378px;
  }
  .span10 {
    width: 1250px;
  }
  .span9 {
    width: 1122px;
  }
  .span8 {
    width: 994px;
  }
  .span7 {
    width: 866px;
  }
  .span6 {
    width: 738px;
  }
  .span5 {
    width: 610px;
  }
  .span4 {
    width: 482px;
  }
  .span3 {
    width: 354px;
  }
  .span2 {
    width: 226px;
  }
  .span1 {
    width: 98px;
  }
  .offset12 {
    margin-left: 1566px;
  }
  .offset11 {
    margin-left: 1438px;
  }
  .offset10 {
    margin-left: 1310px;
  }
  .offset9 {
    margin-left: 1182px;
  }
  .offset8 {
    margin-left: 1054px;
  }
  .offset7 {
    margin-left: 926px;
  }
  .offset6 {
    margin-left: 798px;
  }
  .offset5 {
    margin-left: 670px;
  }
  .offset4 {
    margin-left: 542px;
  }
  .offset3 {
    margin-left: 414px;
  }
  .offset2 {
    margin-left: 286px;
  }
  .offset1 {
    margin-left: 158px;
  }
  .row-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  .row-fluid:before,
  .row-fluid:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
  }
  .row-fluid:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.9920318725099602%;
    *margin-left: 1.9388403831482581%;
  }
  .row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .row-fluid .controls-row [class*="span"] + [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 1.9920318725099602%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.94680851063829%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span11 {
    width: 91.50066401062416%;
    *width: 91.44747252126245%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span10 {
    width: 83.00132802124833%;
    *width: 82.94813653188662%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span9 {
    width: 74.5019920318725%;
    *width: 74.4488005425108%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span8 {
    width: 66.00265604249668%;
    *width: 65.94946455313497%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span7 {
    width: 57.503320053120845%;
    *width: 57.450128563759144%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span6 {
    width: 49.00398406374502%;
    *width: 48.95079257438332%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span5 {
    width: 40.504648074369186%;
    *width: 40.451456585007485%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span4 {
    width: 32.005312084993356%;
    *width: 31.952120595631655%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span3 {
    width: 23.50597609561753%;
    *width: 23.45278460625583%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span2 {
    width: 15.006640106241699%;
    *width: 14.953448616879998%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span1 {
    width: 6.507304116865869%;
    *width: 6.454112627504167%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset12 {
    margin-left: 103.98406374501992%;
    *margin-left: 103.8776807662965%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset12:first-child {
    margin-left: 101.99203187250995%;
    *margin-left: 101.88564889378654%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset11 {
    margin-left: 95.48472775564409%;
    *margin-left: 95.37834477692067%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset11:first-child {
    margin-left: 93.49269588313412%;
    *margin-left: 93.3863129044107%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset10 {
    margin-left: 86.98539176626825%;
    *margin-left: 86.87900878754483%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset10:first-child {
    margin-left: 84.99335989375828%;
    *margin-left: 84.88697691503486%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset9 {
    margin-left: 78.48605577689243%;
    *margin-left: 78.37967279816901%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset9:first-child {
    margin-left: 76.49402390438246%;
    *margin-left: 76.38764092565904%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset8 {
    margin-left: 69.9867197875166%;
    *margin-left: 69.88033680879319%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset8:first-child {
    margin-left: 67.99468791500664%;
    *margin-left: 67.88830493628322%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset7 {
    margin-left: 61.48738379814077%;
    *margin-left: 61.38100081941736%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset7:first-child {
    margin-left: 59.49535192563081%;
    *margin-left: 59.388968946907404%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset6 {
    margin-left: 52.98804780876495%;
    *margin-left: 52.88166483004154%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset6:first-child {
    margin-left: 50.996015936254985%;
    *margin-left: 50.88963295753158%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset5 {
    margin-left: 44.48871181938911%;
    *margin-left: 44.3823288406657%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset5:first-child {
    margin-left: 42.49667994687915%;
    *margin-left: 42.390296968155745%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset4 {
    margin-left: 35.98937583001327%;
    *margin-left: 35.88299285128988%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset4:first-child {
    margin-left: 33.99734395750332%;
    *margin-left: 33.890960978779916%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset3 {
    margin-left: 27.49003984063745%;
    *margin-left: 27.383656861914048%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset3:first-child {
    margin-left: 25.49800796812749%;
    *margin-left: 25.391624989404086%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset2 {
    margin-left: 18.99070385126162%;
    *margin-left: 18.88432087253822%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset2:first-child {
    margin-left: 16.99867197875166%;
    *margin-left: 16.892289000028256%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset1 {
    margin-left: 10.49136786188579%;
    *margin-left: 10.384984883162385%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset1:first-child {
    margin-left: 8.49933598937583%;
    *margin-left: 8.392953010652427%;
  }
  input,
  textarea,
  .uneditable-input {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .controls-row [class*="span"] + [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  input.span12,
  textarea.span12,
  .uneditable-input.span12 {
    width: 1492px;
  }
  input.span11,
  textarea.span11,
  .uneditable-input.span11 {
    width: 1364px;
  }
  input.span10,
  textarea.span10,
  .uneditable-input.span10 {
    width: 1236px;
  }
  input.span9,
  textarea.span9,
  .uneditable-input.span9 {
    width: 1108px;
  }
  input.span8,
  textarea.span8,
  .uneditable-input.span8 {
    width: 980px;
  }
  input.span7,
  textarea.span7,
  .uneditable-input.span7 {
    width: 852px;
  }
  input.span6,
  textarea.span6,
  .uneditable-input.span6 {
    width: 724px;
  }
  input.span5,
  textarea.span5,
  .uneditable-input.span5 {
    width: 596px;
  }
  input.span4,
  textarea.span4,
  .uneditable-input.span4 {
    width: 468px;
  }
  input.span3,
  textarea.span3,
  .uneditable-input.span3 {
    width: 340px;
  }
  input.span2,
  textarea.span2,
  .uneditable-input.span2 {
    width: 212px;
  }
  input.span1,
  textarea.span1,
  .uneditable-input.span1 {
    width: 84px;
  }
  .thumbnails {
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
  .thumbnails > li {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .row-fluid .thumbnails {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can plug in your customised values here:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: You can NOT use the customizer at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html unless you drop and replace the 1200px grid