# How extend bootstrap classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, components, extend

I am doing my first steps with Bootstrap Twitter, and need to extend components. 
For example, I would like to change the navbar background, but without changing the original css file.

I tried to create a new class `.test` with the new background:

```
.test{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

And I've invoked it in the hmtl as:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top test">
```

But, it doesn't work.
How can do this?

Comment: Did my answer work? I see that you've asked another Bootstrap CSS override question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355943/change-vertical-divider-navbar

Comment: You should accept the answer so others know it's resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways to customize/extend Bootstrap classes which are all discussed here: [Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices)

If you intend to override the boostrap styles with your own custom CSS you should avoid using `!important` as this is generally a bad practice.

In the case of the `navbar`, the element that has the background-color is `navbar-inner` so you'd want to override like this:

```
.test .navbar-inner{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Custom navbar example: http://bootply.com/61032

---

[How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass)

Comment: > There are 2 few ways…


Did you mean "There are 2 ways…" or "There are too few ways…"? Just checking so I understand this answer correctly.