# Change vertical divider navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, divider

I'm trying to change the background image of vertical divider class, in Bootstrap.
I have this menu:

```html
<div class="navbar">
     <div class="navbar-inner">
          <a class="brand" href="#"></a>
          <ul class="nav">
               <li class="active"><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
               <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
               <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Galer&iacute;a de fotos</a></li>
               <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

In my css I try:

```css
 .navbar .nav .divider-vertical{
     background-image: url("img/nav-div.jpg");    
 }
```

But nothing. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because its inner width is 0, as only margins add up to outer width:

```css
.divider-vertical {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 9px;
    border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

You need to add the inner width to it, e.g.

```css
.navbar .nav .divider-vertical{
     width: 20px;
     background-image: url("img/nav-div.jpg");    
}
```

You will probably need to lower the margins of the element to compensate for the added width (if you need `.divider-vertical` to stay `20px` width).

Answer (score 1):

This styling pretty much worked for me:

```
<style>
  .navbar-nav > li {border-right: 1px solid #666;}
  .navbar-nav {border-left: 1px solid #666;}
</style>
```

It magically covers the left and right borders of the main menu and the login area menu.