# Twitter Bootstrap Extend File

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like some clarification on what bootstrap-extend.css is. I have seen on many sites and even a template that I had purchased includes however I am unsure of its purpose. The file contains more CSS. Is it a personalized version of bootstrap ontop of the already included bootstrap file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348482/how-extend-bootstrap-classes

Comment: So from my understanding then is that its additional overrides for bootstrap that are specific to the template theme based off the bootstrap framework? Is that correct?