# twitter bootstrap navbar customization beginner query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is my navbar code :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="sampale.html"><font color="#125EAA">Downloads</font></a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="https://example.com">Browser</a></li>
            </ul>
                <div class="btn-group">
                      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Guides
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <!-- dropdown menu links -->
                        <li><a href="https://example.com/sample.htm">User Guide 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://example.com/sample.htm">Option 2</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </div> <!-- dropdown -->

                <div class="btn-group">
                      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">

                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </a>
```

and this is my css file ( custom.css )

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {

                 background-color: #FFDD00; /* fallback color, place your own */
                 background-image: none;
                 background-repeat: no-repeat;
                 filter: none;
              }
```

Result is :

1. In the code portion Browser

   Browser

the background of the Browser portion still shows the default color ( black ) but I want it to show the background-color of yellow (#FFDD00).Can we fix that part ?

1. Also , can we edit the btn-primary class in css . I want to change the color of the button.

I had these 2 questions. Any help greatly appreciated ! danke!

Comment: possible duplicate of [navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869610/navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap)- you also asked this yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661211/bootstrap-custom-css-file

Comment: do you mean the body shows black? if thats the cause just set body{background: #FFDD000;}

Comment: @ParkerHutchinson - no sir, I don't want to make the body yellow , Just the navbar ! and in the browser part it's showing the Browser part as black !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question use:

```
background-color: #FFDD00 !important;
```

For your second use:

```
.btn-primary {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: the background color part goes part of .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner ?

Comment: for the btn-primary part , i can see the background-color of the button red ( I can faintly make it out ) ! But the button color remains unchanged ! I want the button color to change!

Also , regarding the 1st input , I had already used it inside the navbar part if u can see the question. But it doesn't work =/

Comment: Have you put in the external css files

Comment: I didn't put all my codes though should I ? Becoz , i don't know if it can handle twitter bootstrap elements . but I updated it now !

Comment: Found the issue there was a background-image as well here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/CscBP/5/

Comment: ok ! so I am seeing u just added !important to the css file ?

Comment: yep plus you need the `background-image: none !important;`

Comment: i added those to my css file but it still didn't change anything :(

Comment: Have you looked at the fiddle

Comment: If you wan the border on the bottom back remove `border-bottom: none !important`

Comment: Please can you accept as I have done what you asked and possibly upvote as I did to you