# How I change a Less variable of Bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded Twitter Bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

and now I would change some proprieties such as @body-bg or @navbar-default-bg.
Before Bootstrap, I used Zurb Foundation and I changed "foundation_and_override.sass" file. Is there something similar for Bootstrap?

My project is on **Ruby on Rails**

Answer (score 0):

Check out this similar question. It shouldn't matter which exact file you put it in.. all the css will get compiled in your assets directory in rails.

[Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this bootstrap gem](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails) in Rails, it's well maintained and up to date. The variables are defined [here](https://github.com/yury/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss), so you know which value to set before your `@import 'twitter/bootstrap'` statement as shown [in the Readme](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails#stylesheets).

I'm using this exact same approach and am quite happy with it.