# What is mixins in bootstrap less

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have downloaded bootstrap less. I saw one mixin folder inside it containing files with same name. e.g alert.less. So what is the use of mixin files.

And what are the best practices to customize less file. a small example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap also has a huge list of mixins that you can use in your own Less. These mixins allow you to quickly add common attributes to any styles you make. And with the way that Less lets you use parameters, you don’t have to do anything but specify how you want things to appear. For instance, one of the more common needs is a gradient. Bootstrap has a mixin already made, so all you need to do in your style is add this inside of the style you want it to mix into

[Check this out for example](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial)

Comment: @veerendra- what is the best way to override bootstrap less files

Comment: @Beginner You can have all the approaches described here :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices