# Any way to add a breakpoint in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is there any way to add a 5th breakpont to 4 that already exist? Unfortunaetly, 4 is not enough for a project we currenty work on. the idea was to create a new break point screen-hd, which is more than 1400px. Is there easy way to do it?

Comment: I think you will have to edit bootstrap.css in the /css folder in your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a good practice to grab the [less](http://lesscss.org/) files of bootstrap and just produce a new CSS in the way you need. The first approach is to use **variables.less** file, that file contains usually all that you need.

For what you need to customize there are many variables, for example you can change the number of columns altering the variable `grid-columns` and also change the breakpoints.

```
//== Media queries breakpoints
//
//## Define the breakpoints at which your layout will change, adapting to different screen sizes.

// Extra small screen / phone
//** Deprecated `@screen-xs` as of v3.0.1
@screen-xs:                  480px;
//** Deprecated `@screen-xs-min` as of v3.2.0
@screen-xs-min:              @screen-xs;
//** Deprecated `@screen-phone` as of v3.0.1
@screen-phone:               @screen-xs-min;

// Small screen / tablet
//** Deprecated `@screen-sm` as of v3.0.1
@screen-sm:                  768px;
@screen-sm-min:              @screen-sm;
//** Deprecated `@screen-tablet` as of v3.0.1
@screen-tablet:              @screen-sm-min;

// Medium screen / desktop
//** Deprecated `@screen-md` as of v3.0.1
@screen-md:                  992px;
@screen-md-min:              @screen-md;
//** Deprecated `@screen-desktop` as of v3.0.1
@screen-desktop:             @screen-md-min;

// Large screen / wide desktop
//** Deprecated `@screen-lg` as of v3.0.1
@screen-lg:                  1200px;
@screen-lg-min:              @screen-lg;
//** Deprecated `@screen-lg-desktop` as of v3.0.1
@screen-lg-desktop:          @screen-lg-min;

// So media queries don't overlap when required, provide a maximum
@screen-xs-max:              (@screen-sm-min - 1);
@screen-sm-max:              (@screen-md-min - 1);
@screen-md-max:              (@screen-lg-min - 1);


//== Grid system
//
//## Define your custom responsive grid.

//** Number of columns in the grid.
@grid-columns:              12;
//** Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
// Navbar collapse
//** Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-sm-min;
//** Point at which the navbar begins collapsing.
@grid-float-breakpoint-max: (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1);
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L281-L332

It's also good to get familiar with CSS preprocessors as [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less) and [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass), they are becoming a standard these days.

See also [Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10505295/2739274)

Good luck!

Comment: Thankfully this will be easier in Bootstrap 4 thanks to SASS http://www.codeply.com/go/mPS4Yros4U

Answer (score 2):

I use this in my project:

```
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    @for $i from 1 through 12 {
        $width: $i / 12 * 100;
        .col-xl-#{$i} {
            width: unquote($width + '%');
            float: left;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Nice short and clean.

Answer (score 0):

On **Bootstrap 3**, adding a breakpoint is not simple.

As indicated in this [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10203), you must add your own.

Here is a sample code to add new breakpoint with a [sass file](https://gist.github.com/andyl/6360906) or a [css file](https://gist.github.com/andyl/6451936).

Answer (score -1):

you can create a custom css file and customize your columns as follows:

```
.grid-seven .col-md-1 { width: 14.285714285714%; }
.grid-seven .col-md-2 { width: 28.571428571429%; }
.grid-seven .col-md-3 { width: 42.857142857143%; }
.grid-seven .col-md-4 { width: 57.142857142857%; }
.grid-seven .col-md-5 { width: 71.428571428571%; }
.grid-seven .col-md-6 { width: 85.714285714286%; }
.grid-seven .col-md-7 { width: 100%; }
```

For your case you have to use grid-five

```
.grid-five .col-md-1 { width: 20%; }
.grid-five .col-md-2 { width: 40%; }
.grid-five .col-md-3 { width: 60%; }
.grid-five .col-md-4 { width: 80%; }
.grid-five .col-md-5 { width: 100%; }
```

the html is like this:

```
<div class='row grid-five'>
    <div class='col-md-1'>this will take 1/5th of the row</div>
    <div class='col-md-2'>this will take 2/5th of the row</div>
</div>
<div class='row grid-seven'>
    <div class='col-md-1'>this will take 1/7th of the row</div>
    <div class='col-md-2'>this will take 2/7th of the row</div>
</div>
```

This would in no way affect the default bootstrap grid system so you are safe. Keep in mine that grid-seven and grid-five are classes I created myself so you can create your own classes. `grid7, grid-5, grid5 grid-7` or just use the one I used

Comment: Nice! Just remember to use a custom css file, never change Bootstrap's css directly. Because of two main reasons: It's structure is already done, and imagine the headache to apply your customizations when you try to update Bootstrap.

Comment: @DimasPante thanks for the heads up. updated my answer. I didn't mention it because I thought it was obvious to create a custom file but i realised i sounded like: edit the bootstrap.css