# Tools to optimize (remove redundancy and merge) CSS?

Tags: css, compression, minify, yui-compressor

I'm searching for a good CSS compress, merge and optimization tool. I have found tools that clean the CSS but they don't optimize the overwrites.

Here is a basic example:

`a{color:#000}`

and on another line the `a` color is overwritten with this:

`a{color:#fff}`

Does anyone know of a tool that can clean the unused CSS, that was overwritten  and keep just the applied style?

Comment: I edited the title. Just "compression" and "minifying" are orthogonal to actual smart-optimization of CSS. This is a fairly interesting question, although I would normally vote-to-close such "find me a tool" questions ..

Comment: [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) is a OS X application for things like that. Not sure if it does the specifics though.

Comment: Tks pst .Tks Whymarrh,but I can't test CodeKit app, I'm a Win/Linux user :)

Comment: @LucianPovatanu maybe something from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions) will help.

Comment: @Whymarrh tks for that link, but what I was asking is a tool that can clean used or unused css overwrites, so an "unused css cleaner" isnt the answer.

Comment: I just responded to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320591/how-to-check-for-duplicate-css-rules. Try CSSBurner - it seems to be able to optimize in the way you are looking for. CSSLint has nice UI but doesn't seem to do what you are asking for

Comment: Just updated our Node JS tool: http://rbtech.github.io/css-purge

Answer (score 21):

I don't particularly understand what you mean by "clean unused CSS", but in any case, I'll throw two tools at you, and maybe one will work (*the good ol' shotgun approach*).

[CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/) seems to point out "duplicate properties". There are a [range](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/should-you-start-using-csslint/) [of articles](http://www.smashingninja.com/webdesign/csslint-check-your-css-code/) covering some of what it does. But a test with the two definitions you had,

```
a { color: #fff; }
a { color: #000; }
```

it didn't do much of anything. While ...

[Code Beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/) did combine the two selectors, opting for the latter of the two (i.e. the style that's actually applied). Resulting in:

```
a {
  color:#000;
}
```

Comment: "Merge duplicate properties" is the tool that I was searching, tks @Whymarrh

Comment: I found this site helpful while searching for this sort of thing too ... just FYI: http://refresh-sf.com/

Comment: Just updated our Node JS tool: http://rbtech.github.io/css-purge