# Put css properties in same class - Atom

Tags: css, formatting, atom-editor

I'm looking for a website, key-combination, or package which does this:

Is there an easy way to tidy up my css code, and put all the class properties together. I mean if I have code css like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #499eb9;
}

body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Is there a quick way to make it look like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #499eb9;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

This of course is in much longer css code. I have searched on google, but couldn't work out how to word this.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Because it looks like you've answered your own question; simply move all the styles from each different rule into one and then delete the extra, now empty rules.

Comment: I want to know if there is a tool which will do this automatically

Comment: Just saw the last line (sorry, I'm on a phone). Unfortunately, SO isn't the place to ask for software/tool recommendations.

Comment: Where would you recommend?

Comment: Maybe one of the other SE sites might cover it. Couldn't tell you which, though.

Comment: Code Beautifier is a website option, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12518810/5858974)