# How to sort css selectors without losing whitespace and comments?

Tags: css, sorting, gruntjs, css-selectors

I'm about to tidy up some CSS files. The stylesheets are pretty messed up and some selectors appear all over the script. I already used the css comb grunt task to tidy up the properties within the selectors but now I'm looking for something to merge and sort the selectors. I already checked out the cssc grunt plugin and it has kind of what I'm looking for. It's option parameters `sortSelectors`, `sortDeclarations`, `consolidateViaDeclarations`, `consolidateViaSelectors` and `consolidateMediaQueries` do the job. But unfortunately they "mess up" the code and remove comments, whitespaces, linebreaks etc.

I'm not looking for a uglifier/minifier - I'm looking for something to sort the code and make it more readable. Is there any option or another tool that could do that?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: I don't get it. you want to `beautify` or `minify`?

Comment: @Aziz: No, I create a minified version of it later. I want a clean css file to develop with. I don't want a file where I have the same selector several times all over the script with possible double declarations. For example if I have a selector #wrapper.a_class #my_selector and elsewhere in the script #wrapper.another_class #my_selector I want those selectors nearby in the stylesheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tools to optimize (remove redundancy and merge) CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451354/tools-to-optimize-remove-redundancy-and-merge-css)

Comment: It's not a duplicate - my problem is more specific I'd say. It's just about sorting the selectors...

Comment: Then please provide a sample code and expected "optimized" result.