# How to detect unused css elements

Tags: css

How could i remove all unused css elements from my page.i have used many tools but all are telling me the percentage of unused css but no one is telling me which css element to remove..
**i just want to know my unused css elements.**

Comment: If your HTML is properly structured it shouldn't be a problem for you to just look at a couple of pages on your website to discover what is unused... This isn't something you'd use an external tool for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to identify unused css definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions)

Comment: I really don't understand why so many downvotes for this question

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, what if he supports big project with many pages?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, i have 90 html pages and 300kb of css,now what would you suggest me to do..??

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the Firefox extension:

Dust-Me at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/.

"Dust-Me Selectors is development tool that scans your website to find unused CSS selectors."