# Remove unused css and javascript from a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We have a web application which is written in jsp, struts, with lots of css, javascript, jquery. Its a very old application so there are lots of js and css which is written. Since its a very old application there are lots of code written. Now we are in the process of cleaning up the application. Is there is any tool to identify unused js or css?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions

Answer (score 3):

Use this below site to detect the unused css

http://unused-css.com/

Firefox addon- its shows inside a firebug

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10704/

Answer (score 0):

maybe the flows are usefull。

- firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/
- chrome https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/