# How to find out and get rid of unused CSS code?

Tags: html, css

so I have a Github Pages website, and there's a default CSS file that comes along. I basically wiped the slate clean and I'm not using any of their HTML code, but I wanted to see if there was a utility or something that can list out uncalled CSS rules so I can get rid of them. Anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Firefox Extension [Dust-Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) or *Chrome Developer Tools* that called **Audits**.

> Inspect -> Audits tab -> Run -> Remove unused CSS rules.

or Try this [site](https://unused-css.com/).

---

also you can refer to this question [Tool to identify unused css definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions)