# How do I find out which CSS rules are applied on a specific page?

Tags: css

Is there any method or extension to see which CSS rules are applied on a page? For example, span rule does not apply to anything.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div{
        background: grey;
        line-height: 64px;
        width:64px;
        height:64px;
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
        font-family:verdana;
        font-size:35px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    div:hover{
        background-color:#3b5998;
    }
    span {
        background-color:black;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div>
    f
</div>
```

If I can see only the rules applied, I can delete unnecessary rules so that, page can load faster.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/how-to-identify-unused-css-definitions

Comment: You are supposed to search the internet (use Google) for answers before asking a question here. Try `purify CSS` and `CSS performance` for starters.

Comment: [CSS Dust Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) is another one, that tells you which CSS rules are not used on a site.

Comment: There are addons for this, for starters you can use view page source or inspect element.

Comment: I ask questions here when I cannot find answers on google or when I don't know how to query on google. So, thanks for the queries!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to Inspect your page? (Ctrl+Shift+i on chrome)

Comment: While inspecting might work for very small web pages, when dealing with large applications or with frameworks you need better tools for code cleanup. CSS performance is an important issue in today's web only using Inspector you can't get too far.

Answer (score -1):

use browser developer tool for shortcuts ctrl+shift+I or f12 or right click and click inspect elements which tag u want to find out..

then click one html tag it show which css is used inside bar

Comment: Please see Andrei's comment to [RLin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40204161/3536236)s answer.