# Is there a way to get a list of all the CSS applied to a HTML fragment or page?

Tags: html, css, analysis

I know it's easy to get the CSS that is applied to a single node in HTML, using tools like the Firebug extension for Firefox, etc.

But is there a way to see *all* the CSS that is in effect on an entire page, or a larger fragment of HTML?

Specifically, we are cleaning up our one extremely large CSS file into smaller modules and would like to find out what CSS is used on a certain page, so we can move all the non-used CSS to another module.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions

Answer (score 6):

Thank you all! These are the various solutions I've looked at now from your recommendations (collected here for people with the same problem):

**Dust-Me Selectors** (Firefox Add-on)
*This does exactly what I need. Lists used and unused CSS selectors (for the current page, or the entire site, after spidering), and can dump both lists as CSV text. Great.*
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/5392/

**CSS Usage** (Firefox Add-on)
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/10704/

**WARI** - Web Application Resource Inspector (Java tool)
*Appears to only handle static code, not dynamically generated HTML as is present in most web applications that use ajax – which, unfortunately, makes it useless, at least for me*
http://wari.konem.net/

**CSS Redundancy Checker** (Ruby script, requires Rubygems and Hpricot)
http://code.google.com/p/css-redundancy-checker/

**TopStyle** (Windows-only application, $79.95 (!!))
http://svanas.dynip.com/topstyle/

These are all cross-platform and free, except for TopStyle.

Answer (score 3):

As far as tools go, you could use the [css usage plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10704/) for firebug. It will analyze pages for used css.

Or were you looking for a way to do it more programmaticly?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392/), it's add-on for firefox, if you use firebug, as you stated, you may find useful [CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10704/).