# Tool to retrieve CSS properties affecting to the selected Text in a browser?

Tags: css, selectedtext

As you know in any browser you can select a 'piece' of the website and  you can get the HTML code for your selection,

well,

is there any tool you can do the same and it shows you the CSS that only afects to your selection?

EDIT

I know you can get the CSS affecting a tag using Firebug, but how about getting the CSS affecting a larger selection of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool I was looking for

Dust-Me Selectors (Firefox Add-on)
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/5392/

but it's not supported by firefox 6 i needed to downgrade.. (its in developement, dough)

Answer (score 0):

Yes: http://getfirebug.com/

Use the "Inspect element" option.

Comment: yes but this way you need to look tag by tag, lets say i want to select half of the view for a website

Answer (score 0):

Fore developing, you can use Firefox addon FireBug, and for Chrome and IE, there are developer console under F12 key, that allows you to select DOM element, and see all set properties.

Answer (score 0):

With firebug in firefox you can use the **inspect element** tool:

- use the mouse, click on any part of the page
- you'll see in the right
  bottom of the screen the CSS of that part of the page.

There you get all the CSS values hierarchy, even the superseded values.
Also, you can copy all, selecting and copying

Comment: Yes, I saw it now. You could try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564379/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-css-applied-to-a-html-fragment-or-page