# Deleting not-used css property easily

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I have used lots of code segments for some reasons, like templates, side-bars etc from lots of websites. So that, in my code, i have many not-used css properties. Is there any commands in dreamweaver or any other program to delete not-used css attributes easily?
I am asking this because it will take several hours just to delete them. Image how much it is:)
Thanks

Comment: To make it precise, i added the whole css file and just configure the necessary parts that i like from the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the site online? If so you can try this site [Removed unused CSS](http://unused-css.com/).

Also check out the following SO questions they mention the [Dust-Me Selector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) indicated in the comments:

- [How can I find unused images and CSS styles in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website)
- [How to identify unused css definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions)

Comment: very neat, I also found a similar tool called [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/)

Comment: Actually it is what i needed for a later time. Only problem is my site is on the localhost right now:( And I think the solutions you provided for the sites online. Is there any solutions for offline sites?

Comment: I think you can use the Firefox add-on offline as well. You would just need to open the page through a local url.