# Automatically remove unused CSS from a project

Tags: php, css

I have a 3 CSS stylesheets with about 9500 lines.  Some of these selectors are called from within functions. A large number of these selectors are now obsolete.  Is there any program out there that can scan a php website project and automatically remove selectors that are not in use?  I'm developing, so my website is on localhost.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website

Comment: You may also try "Audits" option from Chrome's developer toolbar.
It really helped me. Have a try. :)

Comment: When using this tools keep in mind that some css styles on your page are just there so jQuery can find something. They might not have a rule in the css definitions but are needed.

Answer (score 0):

http://unused-css.com/

this will help you. and there are many other this kind of website will help you lot.