# How to really find all unused css styles on a website

Tags: css, refactoring, dead-code

For refactoring purposes, I am trying to find all unused css style definitions on my website. After googling a while I found various tools like Google Chrome's Audit feature or the Firefox add-on called "dust-me selectors": [How can I find unused images and CSS styles in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website)

For me these tools don't work because:

1. While running, they will only trigger Chrome or Firefox specific css, which means other code like e.g. styles for IE-specific stuff which is included via IE conditional comments, will be marked as being unused although that's not true.
2. These tools will only work for the page that I am currently looking at. So if I have 1 big css file for all my pages, these tools will mark a decent amount of styles as being unused for the one page I am looking at although they could be required on other pages because switching pages will make these tools "forget" they last state.

Are there any free tools out there that let me find unused css styles taking cross-browsers and multiple pages into consideration?

Comment: If your site is in visual studio you can download a trial for resharper for the unused css styles.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below link to search unused css [Remove Unused CSS](http://gtmetrix.com/remove-unused-css.html)