# Is there a way to check css elements which are not linked to html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with HTML web template, and I want to know if there is a way to check CSS code that is no longer needed. Deleted HTML pages do not need any CSS code related to removed HTML pages. One example is when one CSS covers all pages styling on a specified HTML page, and you remove the HTML page. The CSS code related to the removed HTML page should be removed as well. If you have lots of styling involved in the CSS file, checking unnecessary CSS codes need efforts.

Is there any way to check unused or unnecessary CSS code?

Comment: Please define "remove a HTML page". And especially, how to "remove" a page without removing all the CSS?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website/40725374#40725374

Comment: Question has be answered.  you can also use this firefox addon works similar to link above https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/

Comment: make use of shadow dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use google developer tool to check percent of css not used by your html document. check the link below this will guide you along the way 
 
http://www.labnol.org/internet/remove-unused-css/28635/