# Dreamweaver - Is there a way to clean up css/javascript files and find unused elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

My question is pretty straight forward.

I have multiple CSS and Javascript files in my project, and I'm 90% sure I have a lot of unused css elements that I haven't used. I know Dreamweaver has a lot of features that I've yet to use, and I know there are other IDE's that show you functions and variables that are unused.

Example:
in the Netbeans IDE, if I have a variable that I haven't used, at all, in any file, it underlines said variable, and tells me that It's unused.

Does Dreamweaver offer anything similar, or is there another program that I can use to do this?

Comment: In regards to other ways to do this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/how-to-identify-unused-css-definitions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website). Several answers in each of those; maybe one will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver doesn't seem to have this functionality natively, but [this thread on Adobe's forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/509987) mentions the firefox extension [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) is mentioned there.